# Target Class By radio button checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using three radio buttons for a form. With jQuery i am trying to add class to div which have radio button checked. But it is targeting all divs rather than targeting only the checked div and not removing class of unchecked div.

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zqatxvgs/**

**Html**

```
<form action="">
<div class="field-box">  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br></div>
<div class="field-box">  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br></div>
<div class="field-box">  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('.field-box').addClass("option-selected");
} else {
    $('.field-box').removeClass("option-selected");
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a generic selector rather than targeting current elements parent. You should play around with `this` and `parent`

```js
$('input:radio').change(function(){
  $(".option-selected").removeClass("option-selected");
   if($(this).is(":checked")) {  
    $(this).parent().addClass("option-selected");
   }
});
```

```css
.option-selected {
    background: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
<div class="field-box">  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br></div>
<div class="field-box">  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br></div>
<div class="field-box">  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Wow.. do you feel so ? I can't stop that thought.

Comment: just kidding bro :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is not working when radio is already checked by default. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4tacqvrj/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$(this)` keyword otherwise it'll add class to all the `div` and there is no need of `if` condition. You can simply do like this

```js
$('input:radio').change(function() {
  $('.field-box').removeClass("option-selected");
  $(this).closest('.field-box').addClass("option-selected");
});
```

```css
.option-selected {
  background: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div class="field-box"> <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br></div>
  <div class="field-box"> <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br></div>
  <div class="field-box"> <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other</div>
</form>
```

**P.S** Your logic of `if-else` is also wrong. It will never remove the class from the previous one when another one is checked

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is not working when radio is already checked by default. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4tacqvrj/

Comment: @YOU Simply add a class to the div initially for the radio which is checked like this https://jsfiddle.net/4tacqvrj/2/

Answer (score 0):

just traverse to the parent element to select it and assign the style to it

```
 $('input:radio').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parent('.field-box').addClass("option-selected");
    } else {
        $(this).parent('.field-box').removeClass("option-selected");
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-jquery approach

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Toggle Radio</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
  .option-selected {
  background: yellowgreen;
}
</style>

<form action="" name="genderForm">
<div class="field-box">  <input onchange="highlightRadio()" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br></div>
<div class="field-box">  <input onchange="highlightRadio()" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br></div>
<div class="field-box">  <input onchange="highlightRadio()" type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function highlightRadio() {
    let activeRadioButton = document.querySelector('input[type = "radio"]:checked');
    let allRadioButton = document.querySelectorAll('input[type = "radio"]');
    for(i=0;i<allRadioButton.length;i++) {
      allRadioButton[i].parentElement.classList.remove('option-selected');
    }
    activeRadioButton.parentElement.classList.add('option-selected');    
    return false;
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```